# JVM Tuning advice for alfresco

Tags: performance, jvm, alfresco

I have Centos server (RAM 60Gb) for Alfresco application, I need to tune the JVM, the scenario is 20Gb for Alfresco version 4.2d and 40Gb for other applications.

Please give me the best solution for this.

This is my tuning JVM on file "ctl.sh":

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -Xms8G -Xmx16G -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dalfresco.home=/opt/alfresco -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you have to take into account in order to properly tune your JVM, as reported in [Tuning the JVM](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/jvm-tuning.html).
You cannot expect to have a full performance tuning only looking to available RAM.
Here following a brief summary:

1. Alfresco version

   You didn't mention which version you're using, but in general newer version will require more resources
2. Hardware

   For better performance there are some configuration recommended, depending also on the number of concurrent users
3. Disk usage

How many documents do you expect the system will have to manage? Which is their average size? How often do they change their content? Moreover you have to pay attention to the space required by indexes (Lucene or SolR) and to the fact that usually indexing is a very resource-consuming process.

4. Virtualization

Are you going to use virtualization or a 'real' hardware environment? You can expect performance degradation if you virtualize your servers.

5. Concurrent users
   The more concurrent users (and casual users) you have, the more resources you need.

So, try to answer to all these questions and you should have a clearer idea of which is at least a good performance tuning for your case.